# Android Studio - Evaluar datos y obtener el mayor, en base a eso, imprimir datos

Tags: java, android-studio, condiciones

Buen día amigos.
Estoy haciendo un test vocacional, lo hice con distintas activities y RadioButtons para las respuestas, entonces cada RaddioButton está programado para que guarde un valor en una variable.

Ahora lo que quiero es que con datos almacenados desde los RaddioButtons, verificar qué variable es la que tenga mayor datos guardados, y en base a eso, imprimir datos o como para tomar decisiones.

Les adjunto el código de la lógica de las preguntas:

```
package com.example.testvocacional10;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

//Importar a cada activity para el uso de las variables de las Areas

import static com.example.testvocacional10.Inicio.Valores.Area1_FM;
import static com.example.testvocacional10.Inicio.Valores.Area2_BS;
import static com.example.testvocacional10.Inicio.Valores.Area3_CS;
import static com.example.testvocacional10.Inicio.Valores.Area4_HA;

public class Pregunta7 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Botones básicos para el llenado de las activities
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5;
    TextView tv_respuesta;
    Button btn_aceptar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pregunta7);

        //Conexiones basicas para las preguntas
        rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);
        rb4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb4);
        rb5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb5);
        btn_aceptar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_aceptar);
        tv_respuesta=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_respuesta);

    }

    //Metodo basico para el conteo de las preguntas por area
    public void validar(View view) {

        if (rb1.isChecked() == true) {
            int SArea1 = Area1_FM++;
            String Area1 = String.valueOf(SArea1);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area1);

        } else if (rb2.isChecked() == true) {
            int SArea4 = Area4_HA++;
            String Area4 = String.valueOf(SArea4);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area4);

        } else if (rb3.isChecked() == true) {
            int SArea2 = Area2_BS ++;
            String Area2 = String.valueOf(SArea2);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area2);

        } else if (rb4.isChecked() == true) {
            int SArea3 = Area3_CS++;
            String Area3 = String.valueOf(SArea3);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area3);

        }
```

Entonces los datos que quiero ocupar están almacenados en las variables de hasta arriba (Area 1, Area 2, Area 3, Area 4) y los valores que estén almacenados ahi son los que deseo ocupar, revisar cual es el que tiene el mayor numero y a su vez, mostrar datos que posteriormente agregaré.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en sí?

Comment: Sé que quizás es facil, pero ya me abrumé.
Necesito que al finalizar el test, verifique qué Area es la que tiene más puntos y en base a la que tenga más puntos, poder enviar un texto que diga el area que le corresponde.
Pero no sé como hacer esa parte.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacer lo que quieres, una muy siemple sería usando [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max). Por ejemplo: `int maxArea = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(SArea1, SArea2, SArea3, SArea4));` Ahí tendrías en `maxArea` el mayor entre todos los valores de `sArea...`

Comment: Uf, no estoy familiarizado con esos metodos. ¿Crees que me puedas ayudar siendo más especifico? Con manzanas, por favor. jajaja

Comment: Sin duda, pero es necesario saber qué vas a hacer con el dato. Con ese código `maxArea` sería el número entero mayor entre todos ellos, ¿qué vas  a hacer con él luego? ¿te interesa conocer sólo el valor o te interesa conocer también la variable que posee ese mayor valor?

Comment: Ah, entiendo, ya que tengo el dato más grande o el que tiene más "puntos" por decirlo así, lanzar un mensaje o en la misma Activity con algun boton que diga: "Tu area es la 1" y dependiendo qué variable tenga mayor puntuación que mande mensaje diciendo: "Tu area es la X"

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. Ese detalle es importante para optar por la solución que sea más óptima. Por favor, explícate mejor. ¿Una vez conozcas el mayor valor entre todos, qué hay que hacer?

Comment: Hmm... Imagina que alguien contestó un cuestionario con preguntas previas.
Cada pregunta almacena un dato de tipo entero, si eligió la respuesta A, suma un 1 a la variable Area 1, si eligió la segunda respuesta suma un 1 al Area 2, y así, son 4 variables.

Lo que quiero hacer es, tomar el Area que tenga más puntos, en base a eso, quiero mostrar una pantalla que diga, el Area que te conviene más es  "x", esa "x" llevará algo que diga, tu area es la 1, o la 2, o la 3, o la 4, en base a la que tenga más puntos.

Comment: Entonces realmente no te interesa obtener el mayor dato, sino **el área que tiene el mayor dato**. Son dos cosas distintas. Para simplificarlo quizá convendría que trabajes con algo así como un `HashMap`, si es que puedes cambiar el código

Comment: Sí, el codigo lo estoy haciendo yo, pero tengo muchos problemas para hacerlo.
De cierta manera sí, necesito saber que area tiene mayor dato para que imprima el Dato de: "Tu area es x" pensaba en hacerlo con if else if, o algo similar. ¿Crees que se pueda? No he manejado eso de HashMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un `HashMap` para esto, por ejemplo (ver comentarios que agregué en el código).

```
public class Pregunta7 extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Botones básicos para el llenado de las activities
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5;
    TextView tv_respuesta;
    Button btn_aceptar;
    //Declaras el HashMap como miembro de la clase
    private HashMap<String, Integer> mapAreas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Lo inicializas en el onCreate
        mapAreas = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        // ... resto del código del onCreate

    }


    public void validar(View view) {
        //En cada bloque Asignas una clave SArea1, 2, 3  y le sumas 1 cada vez
        if (rb1.isChecked() == true) {
            mapAreas.merge("SArea1", 1, Integer::sum);
            int SArea1 = Area1_FM++;
            String Area1 = String.valueOf(SArea1);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area1);

        } else if (rb2.isChecked() == true) {
            mapAreas.merge("SArea2", 1, Integer::sum);
            int SArea4 = Area4_HA++;
            String Area4 = String.valueOf(SArea4);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area4);

        } else if (rb3.isChecked() == true) {
            mapAreas.merge("SArea3", 1, Integer::sum);
            int SArea2 = Area2_BS ++;
            String Area2 = String.valueOf(SArea2);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area2);

        } else if (rb4.isChecked() == true) {
            mapAreas.merge("SArea4", 1, Integer::sum);
            int SArea3 = Area3_CS++;
            String Area3 = String.valueOf(SArea3);
            tv_respuesta.setText(Area3);

        }
    }

}
```

Luego, donde necesites saber cuál tiene el mayor valor haces simplemente algo como esto:

```
String maxArea = Collections.max(mapAreas.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

Ahí tendrás en `maxArea` el valor `SArea1, SArea2, SArea3 o SArea4` que tenga mayor puntuación.

Comment: Ahhh, ya entiendo. Parece no ser tan complicado.
Y una pregunta, ¿Cómo podría hacerle para que en lugar del valor más alto, salga algo como: "Tu area es la 1, 2, 3 o 4"? Sería con un setText o algo similar?

Comment: Pones cada caso así: `mapAreas.merge("1", 1, Integer::sum);` o sea, pones `1,2,3...` a la izquierda de cada map en vez de `SArea...`  y al obtener `maxArea` le puedes agregar `"Tu áreas es: "`